# Is there a way to convert a game made with ImpactJS to Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, html5-canvas, impactjs

I know that is possible export Unity projects to WebGL, but is there a way to use code from a ImpactJS project on Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the web for converter and found none, so unless I missed something, what you are trying to do is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a way to convert. Sometimes it may require some manual fixing. Generally most languages are similar enough that you can automate many parts. The art assets are often re-usable, for example.

Answer (score 0):

No. Unity converts it's own framework and system of gameobjects and c# code that you write into WebGL code.
However, if you have computing and business code that does not do much with the canvas/UI then that code can be copied over somewhat. For code that is purely computational or business logic, you can use any online tool to convert javascript into C# code with some success.
My guess is that if most of your code dealt with the canvas and UI and interaction, that none of that code will be able to be reused.